# Ask user for path for fopen in C?

Tags: path, fopen

This is my function. It's working absolutely fine; I just can't get one more thing working.
Instead of the static fopen paths, I need the user to write the path for the files. I tried several things but I can't get it working. Please help

```
    int FileToFile() {
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp_write;
    char line[128];
    int max=0;
    int countFor=0;
    int countWhile=0;
    int countDo = 0; 
    fp = fopen("d:\\text.txt", "r+");
    fp_write = fopen("d:\\results.txt", "w+");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("Greshka");

    }
    else {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
            countFor = 0;
            countWhile = 0;
            countDo = 0;
            fputs(line, stdout);

            if (line[strlen(line)-1] = "\n") if (max < (strlen(line) -1)) max = strlen(line) -1;
            else if (max < strlen(line)) max = strlen(line);
            char *tmp = line;
            while (tmp = strstr(tmp, "for")){
                countFor++;
                tmp++;
            }

            tmp = line; 
            while (tmp = strstr(tmp, "while")){
                countWhile++;
                tmp++;
            }

            tmp = line;
            while (tmp = strstr(tmp, "do")){
                countDo++;
                tmp++;
            }


            fprintf(fp_write, "Na tozi red operatora for go ima: %d pyti\n", countFor);
            fprintf(fp_write, "Na tozi red operatora for/while go ima: %d pyti\n", countWhile - countDo);
            fprintf(fp_write, "Na tozi red operatora do go ima: %d pyti\n", countDo);

        }
        fprintf(fp_write, "Maximalen broi simvoli e:%d\n", max);
        fclose(fp_write);
        fclose(fp);
    }


}
```

Comment: How do you want the user to specify the paths? Through command-line arguments, through interactive input, or in an external file which stores the paths?

Comment: Trough command-line arguments :).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `argc` and `argv`. They are used for command-line arguments passed to a program. This requires that your `main` function be revised as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

The `argc` is an integer that represents the number of command-like arguments, and `argv` is an array of `char*` that contain the arguments themselves. Note that for both, the program name itself counts as an argument.

So if you invoke your program like this:

```
myprog c:\temp
```

Then `argc` will be `2`, `argv[0]` will be `myprog`, and `argv[1]` will be `c:\temp`. Now you can just pass the strings to your function. If you pass more arguments, they will be `argv[2]`, etc.

Keep in mind if your path contains spaces, you must enclose it in double quotes for it to be considered one argument, because space is used as a delimiter:

```
myprog "c:\path with spaces"
```